# Getting touchpad working on MacBook Air

Tags: touchpad, macbook, input-devices

I recently installed Ubuntu on my new MacBook Air 4,2 (Mid 2011).  Everything has worked great so far, with a few minor issues with screen resolution.  However, I am now completely stuck on how to get my touchpad to recognize gestures such as scrolling, tap to click, and right click.  I have run the post-install script [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir4-2), tried installing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics through apt-get and also through Synaptic Package Manager.

So far nothing has helped and when I run synclient as a test I get a message saying "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?".  I added the link ppa:mactel-support/ppa to my software sources.

When I run `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`, I get a pretty lengthy error message :

```
Error! /usr/src/usbhid-0.11.2.dkms.tar.gz does not exist.
dpkg: error processing usbhid-dkms (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems    prevent configuration of bcm5974-dkms:
bcm5974-dkms depends on usbhid-dkms; however:
Package usbhid-dkms is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing bcm5974-dkms (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered    while processing:
   usbhid-dkms
   bcm5974-dkms 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'
```

This leads me to believe that I need to install usbhid-dkms, however searching has yielded no results.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything like run a post-installation script, etc.  Just install 12.04 beta2, which fixes a lot of the issues that plagued MacBook Airs.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that the latest beta of ubuntu https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/TechnicalOverview/Beta2

has brought support for touchpads.

I recommend trying this and seeing if it works.